# How to unit test a void function in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest, void

I am working on a hobby project mainly to learn cpp unit testing and database programming. However I am a little bit lost & confused about how should I write my code for proper testing. I tend to write a lot of **void** functions for my cpp projects. But now I can not figure out how should I test those functions. I have been succeeded in testing non-void functions cause they return something which can be easily tested against a value.

Ami I doing things in an unprofessional way? Should I avoid void functions as much as possible so that I can test those functions ? Or I am missing something ? For example how would I be able to test this function -

`database.cpp`

```cpp
#include "database.hpp"

#include <sqlite3.h>

#include <iostream>

#include "spdlog/sinks/basic_file_sink.h"

// Creating the logging object
auto logger = spdlog::basic_logger_mt("appnotex", "../data/appnotexlog");

void Database::createDb(const char *dbname) {
  // Creating the database file
  sqlite3 *datadb;
  int status = sqlite3_open(dbname, &datadb);

  //    checking for errors
  if (status == SQLITE_OK) {
    logger->info("------------ New Session ----------");
    logger->info("Connected to Database Successfully");
  } else {
    std::string errorMessage = sqlite3_errmsg(datadb);
    logger->info("Error: " + errorMessage);
  }
```

#### If Needed

- I am using **Google Test** framework
- My whole project code hosted - [here](https://github.com/Abir-Tx/AppNotEx)

#### Update

I have tried this one is this approach of testing the above method correct ?

`databaseTest.cpp`

```cpp
TEST(DatabaseTest, createDbTest) {
  const char *dbfilename = "../data/test/data.db";
  const char *tbname = "DataTest";
  Database *db = new Database();

  std::ifstream dbfile("../data/test/data.db");
  bool ok = false;
  if (!dbfile.is_open())
    ok = false;
  else
    ok = true;

  EXPECT_TRUE(ok);
}
```

Comment: functions have more than return values, they have sideeffects. Know what they are and test the preconditions

Comment: So, for the above example I have to test if the database file has been created or not? I do not have to test the function itself? @largest_prime_is_463035818

Comment: I'd recommend focusing your tests on the behaviors you want `Database` to exhibit, rather than the individual functions that are a part of that. Testing individual functions is a way for testing to go wrong. The approach of testing every function can make encapsulation seem like a problem, and refactoring as something to be avoided. Two things that are obviously not true.

Comment: Basically your code has a dependency to `sqlite3` (external code). Functionality of `Database::createDb` is to handle call of `sqlite3` API. So to properly test this you have to provide dependency injection. This means that you have to replace calls to `sqlite3` APi with something what can be translated to `sqlite3` API.
With googletest there is gmock tool to help with testing that.

Comment: Also writing tests after production code is much harder the when you do it in opposite way. When you write test first the you will focus on behaviors which suppose to be tested not on current implementation.

Comment: what others said, don't fixate on return values, in some sense thats implementation details. You need not test whether a function that returns eg an `int` really returns an `int` ;), but you want to test behavior

Comment: In you github there is no `class Database` anywhere! https://github.com/Abir-Tx/AppNotEx/search?q=Database you have forgot to commit important part of code!

Comment: @MarekR there is of course a Database class declared here https://github.com/Abir-Tx/AppNotEx/blob/main/include/AppNotEx/database/database.hpp
 It is also showing in search query.

Ok, I am not aware of dependency injection. I will try to look up on this topic then. Thanks a lot

Comment: @MarekR for some split seconds you made me feel stupid haha !

Comment: I have added another snippet of code in which I tried to test the above function. Is this approach of testing correct as you guys are saying ?

Comment: NO! 1. This doesn't test production code 2. You have memory leak

Comment: This might be a bad place to ask as well, since you have working code that you want to get reviewed, at least to some extent. A better place for that would be to use codereview.stackexchange.com. There are lots of things in your code which you could improve, even if they are already working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not so much in the function returning `void`. Think about how it signals errors and make sure all cases (success and failures) are tested, simple as that.

However, I don't see any error signalling at all there, apart from logging it. As a rule of thumb, logging should only be used for post-mortem research and the like. So, if logging completely fails, your program can still run correctly. That means, nothing internally depends on it and it is not a suitable error handling/signalling mechanism.

Now, there are basically three ways to signal errors:

1. Return values. Typically used in C code and sometimes used in C++ as well. With `void` return, that's not an option, and that is probably the source of your question.
2. Exceptions. You could `throw std::runtime_error("DB connect failed");` and delegate handling it to the calling code.
3. Side effects. You could store the connection state in your `Database` instance. For completeness, using a global `errno` is also possible, but not advisable.

In any case, all three ways can be exercised and verified in unit tests.

Comment: Thanks.  You made it a lot easier and clearer.  I will probably use the throw keyword from now on and I will have to read more on signalling I guess.